# How to declare a variable in a def and then call it from a button in python

Tags: python, function

```
def roll():
    die1 = random.randint(1,6)
    die2 = random.randint(1,6)

A = tkinter.Button(top, text ="Roll!", command = roll)

A.pack()

if die1 == die2:
    print(die1)
```

It said that die1 has not been defined. How do i change it so it is defined. I have tried to do this

```
die1 = random.randint(1,6)

die2 = random.randint(1,6)

def roll():
    die1 = random.randint(1,6)

    die2 = random.randint(1,6)

A = tkinter.Button(top, text ="Roll!", command = roll)

A.pack()

if die1 == die2:
    print(die1)
```

but the numbers don't change if it was repeated

Comment: `die1` and `die2` are *local variables* - they simply do not exist outside of the `roll()` function.  But that's not the fundamental problem here: you are trying to compare these two values immediately after creating the Button, there is absolutely no possibility that `roll()` has been called yet, and therefore you have no values to compare.  Anything that requires the rolled values should be done from inside `roll()` - either directly in that function, or in some other function that it calls (in which case you can pass the two values to that function as parameters).

Answer (score 0):

A very hacky way of achieving that would be:

```
die1 = [random.randint(1, 6)]
die2 = [random.randint(1, 6)]
 
def roll():
    die1[0] = random.randint(1, 6)
    die2[0] = random.randint(1, 6)
```

But I recommend you just make a super simple class so your values are stored inside that class:

```
import random

class Game():
    def__init__(self):
        self.die1 = random.randint(1,6)
        self.die2 = random.randint(1,6)

    def roll(self):
        self.die1 = random.randint(1,6)
        self.die2 = random.randint(1,6)


game = Game()

A = tkinter.Button(top, text ="Roll!", command = game.roll)

A.pack()

if game.die1 == game.die2:
    print(game.die1)
```

You could even remove that **init** function but you would have to call game.roll() before that last if statement otherwise those instance variables won't exist.